# in ionic how to take input from keyboard like this below image in ionic 5

Tags: html, ionic-framework, input, keyboard-events

I want to take input from keyboard like this currency will be fix and when I type any number and point value so amount should be show like this below image. i tried this with super script tag but unfortunately `<sup></sup>` tag doesn't support input. can anyone help if they know about this

[image: strong text]**

Comment: Please clarify more, your question is unclear.

Comment: i have to take input from user like in this way as showed in image in ionic input

Comment: In a normal ion-input it will not be done in this way, i've once worked with ion-input-mask and i remember it have such things, make a search on it.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic-input-mask  this is the link for it.

Comment: Thanks, i went through this link..but how i will show digits in SUP TAG when user enters point(.).and also other case is when user press back key so input should be like shown in image.

Comment: I think you should choose type carrency and give it options of double to get .00 so the input type will be £number.00 but for letting them go as power ^ , i don't know if it can be done, i'll make a search and brb.

Comment: Yes, £number.00  in this way we can easily do but as a power i m also searching.

Comment: Look, i think there is no plugin for that, you can achieve it with normal html and css using divs so you create a div for currency and div for number and another div for double values with attribute contentedittable and by that it will that that shape.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214972/discussion-between-techvalens-and-mostafa-harb).